# Too much [screen] time on Stack Overflow is harmful

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just ran across the [screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) tag a few days ago

Description:

> A screen on a device, such as an iPhone screen or other....

**Can anyone actually be an expert in.... screen?**

Well, let’s see what are the topics that [screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) can cover,

[Top tags used with the [screen] tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=screen)

- [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)
- [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
- [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)[html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)
- [resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolution)[pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixel)
- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows)
- [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout)
- etc...

> **"Yes!, I can be an expert in all of these!" -No one :(**

**- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

*Nope*, not at all. It could mean literally anything from screen resolution to screen capture to desktop/mobile screen, so on and so forth

**- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

It could be related to many programming topics, but the overall definition of the tag does not really have anything to do with programming

**- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It is ambiguous, as I already stated in the first point.

**- Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

What information can you get from the word “screen”? Ah yes, it shows that the question is about screen

> woohoo a new question with the screen tag, it shows that the question is related to screen which is unclear and ambigous, therefore it is a meaningful information! -no one :(

**- Is the tag harmful?**

It could lead to many off-topic questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594942/windows-7-desktop-changes-needed) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582720/what-is-the-maximal-screen-width-of-a-smartphone-in-market-to-consider-for-devel), so.. yes?

Comment: Note that `screen` might also refer to [GNU Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), which lets you detach and reattach ssh sessions. Commands begin with `screen` (e.g. `screen -ls`). I just started using it yesterday!

Comment: yeah, It is also stated in the wiki that *questions about gnu-screen (the terminal application for managing multiple windows) should use the gnu-screen tag.*

Comment: @aheze: FYI, `screen` is pretty old, and if you're just starting to use a terminal multiplexer you might want to read some articles from people recommending ones designed more recently such as `tmux`.  (e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/671422/how-to-use-tmux-on-linux-and-why-its-better-than-screen/).  I still use `screen` (in the increasingly rare cases where I'm not just working locally with multiple Konsole tabs) because I already spent time learning it, and it does work well.

Comment: "Should we \[screen\] out this tag?"

Comment: @aheze I'm not sure if questions about that are on-topic. One doesn't script that use. Maybe Unix.SE

Comment: @khelwood: Yes, that is a glaring omission. Better save on the estate.

Comment: @wp78de but even as a catch phrase, does it add any *value* to the question?  Nobody yet has proposed that it does.

Comment: Tools used by programmers are on-topic, and Screen fits there. It's sometimes used for creating long-lasting sessions (similar to `nohup`), or for collaborative coding sessions.

Comment: So I might turn this into an answer, but ill have to collect links first, anyhow; as far as I can tell, it only adds ambiguity because of how it is used. I see instances where it is used with JS, and should be called _"window"_, rather than _"screen"_. I see cases where it should be a _"page"_, or _"body"_ tag, and not a _"screen"_ tag, in posts that reference HTML. There are cases where it is used as a tag because of software that has an issue with full screen, and In that case, the tag should be _"full screen"_, and not _"screen"_ IMO.

Comment: It's not being used in the context of a developer's tool at all, in fact, almost every post I've seen that is tagged with _"screen"_, uses the _"screen"_ tag in an unacceptable fashion, either one way, or another. I say scrap it.

Comment: The header should better be: "The [screen] tag on Stack Overflow does not meet the tagging standards". I understood the humorous header only after reading, and headers on SE should not draw your attention like newspaper headers, even on meta.

Comment: 'Can you get any meaningful information from the word "Screen"? Nope.' Not true at all. It does tell us that the question is related to screens. Ambiguous != meaningless.  'It could lead to many off-topic questions like this one or this one, so.. yes?' Those examples are not off-topic because of the screen tag. If the screen tag were not applied, they would still be off-topic. I'm not arguing in favor of the screen tag, but the inaccuracy of the above points makes me dubious about the whole proposal to burninate.

Comment: @LarsH yes it does tell us that the question is related to screen, but.... is it meaningful? i dont think so

Comment: I had to connect to another Xserver screen for a Docker container to show up its results on Windows instead. I am against Docker questions on SO, but putting that apart, there, you would have a meaning screen tag, and I do not care whether it is ambiguous since it would help summing up the core problem if you only look at the tags.

Comment: @LarsH i kinda disagree with your first point, i dont think showing that the question is related to screen is meaningful at all, unambigous does not directly mean meaningless but a lot of unambigous tags gives meaningless information, but yes i agree with your second point, my point there is quite innacurate which is why i put a `?` sign :/

Comment: whoops i meant ambigous*

Comment: @I_love_vegetables summing up the "core problem" in tags is not what tags are for.

Comment: @I_love_vegetables: No, *[ambiguous](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=ambigous)*

Comment: @questionto42: If you see a meta question title that involves a [tag] name and a play on words, you can be pretty sure it's about a problem with the way the tag gets used, or an inherent problem with having a tag for that concept.  The wordplay should hint at what kind of problem it is, and the tag name itself is usually obviously ambiguous (like in this case).  There's no need to boringly spell that out in the title.  I wouldn't have clicked on this meta question at all if not for the fun word-play, and I imagine the fun also motivates other people to read and contribute ideas.

Comment: @PeterCordes and to all: I agree, this makes it more colourful. I am just new to that type of meta questions. This header is such a good wordplay that I clicked on it for curiosity. I take back my comments against such headers.

Comment: @PeterCordes regardless of how modern your terminal emulator is, I still use screen whenever I need to fire off a job that needs to keep running after I log off

Comment: @chiliNUT: screen is useful for that if you need to reattach to it later to see TTY output, otherwise you can just use `nohup` to make sure it won't die from SIGHUP when the parent shell exits, or use Bash `disown %1` to detach it without sending a hup.  You can set your shell so nohup is the default for background jobs when the shell exits.  But anyway, on my desktop, I simply don't log out until I'm going to reboot for a kernel update anyway.  Any long running thing I start, I do from a terminal tab I'm not planning to close.

Comment: If we keep the `screen` tag, we might as well use the `keyboard`, `chair`, `desk` tags as well. They provide equivalent context to questions.

Comment: For everyone who keeps talking about the GNU screen command, the wiki specifically states that the `gnu-screen` tag should be used for that use case. That is not what is being discussed here.

Comment: @bryanRayner the `keyboard` tag actually exist xD